# Solving a Dirac-delta integral by integration by parts

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

> Show that
>
> $$-\frac 1 2 \int d^3x'\big (-i \phi(x', t)\nabla'^2\delta^3(x-x') \big ) = i\frac 1 2 \nabla^2\phi(x, t)$$

Attempt

$$-\frac 1 2 \int d^3x'\big (-i \phi( \vec x', t)\nabla'^2\delta^3(\vec x-\vec x') \big ) $$ $$=\frac{i}{2}\phi(\vec x', t) \nabla'  \delta^3(\vec x-\vec x') -\frac{i}{2} \int d^3 x' \nabla' \phi(\vec x', t) \nabla'  \delta^3(\vec x-\vec x')$$ $$=\frac{i}{2}\phi(\vec x', t) \nabla'  \delta^3(\vec x-\vec x') - \frac{i}{2} \nabla'\phi(\vec x', t)  \delta^3(\vec x-\vec x') +  \frac{i}{2} \int d^3 x' \nabla'^2 \phi(\vec x', t) \delta^3(\vec x-\vec x')$$ $$= \frac{i}{2}\phi(\vec x', t) \nabla'  \delta^3(\vec x-\vec x') - \frac{i}{2} \nabla'\phi(\vec x', t)  \delta^3(\vec x-\vec x')+\frac{i}{2}\nabla^2 \phi(\vec x, t)$$

I've been told that $\frac{i}{2}\phi(\vec x', t) \nabla'  \delta^3(\vec x-\vec x'), - \frac{i}{2} \nabla'\phi(\vec x', t)  \delta^3(\vec x-\vec x')$ terms vanish due to 'assuming boundary conditions'. However I do not see how to really show that such statement is true. How to do so?

Comment: If you're a physicist than merely stating that the terms vanish 'assuming boundary conditions' is more than sufficient. It is indeed necessary.

Comment: @uniquesolution I am a physicist but I am not satisfied by simply stating  that the terms vanish 'assuming boundary conditions'. The thing is that I want to understand why this is true and there's no better way to do so than proving it. I've been several days searching and asking for this but still did not find a satisfying answer. I hope I can find it in this post! :)

Comment: You haven't given any domain of integration, but it should be all of space. And since $\delta^3(\vec{x}-\vec{x'}) = 0$ when $\vec{x}-\vec{x'} \neq \vec{0}$ those terms (i.e. those that are said to vanish) certainly vanish at infinity.

Comment: $\nabla’^2 =\nabla^2$

Comment: @md2perpe ahhh that makes sense to me, thanks!

Comment: @FelixMarin yeah, I put $'$ simply as a dummy index :)

Comment: @JD_PM Yes. But it allows you to pull the $\nabla^{2}$ outside of the integral ( assuming you can exchange the $\int$ with de derivative ).